# Referencing static files in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eAz4.png)
[tooltip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Vrj.png)
[searching for the correct path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWhcP.png)
FILES:

**settings.py**
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static" ,
]

**base.html**
{% load static %}

How do I reference my static files in the following line of html code?...

```
<li class="ftco-animate"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook"><span class="ion-logo-facebook"></span></a></li>
```

**i.e.** {% static 'website/...' %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files), assuming your filepath is `BASE_DIR/static/sub_dir/example.pdf` you can reference it like this:

```
<li class="ftco-animate">
    <a href="{% static 'sub_dir/example.pdf' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook">
        <span class="ion-logo-facebook"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

It is good practice to place your static files in a sub-directory named same as your app name. That way, it will be much easier to reference the files from different apps later on. That is why the example in the docs says `{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}`.

Also please make sure you go through the documentations and follow all the steps mentioned there.

Comment: Sakib Hasan I added an img at the top of the question here to show what I am dealing with. Still having trouble grabbing the file. kind of a newbie.

Comment: it was pre coded html template that i am trying to integrate into my project

Comment: Where is your  `tooltip` give that path to static.

Comment: Which file are you trying to reference there? Write the full path of that file starting from `NFT_Nerdz/` (as shown in your screenshot) and it should be fine unless there is another problem somewhere else. You can debug the problem by examining your browsers inspect tool.

Comment: Sakib Hassan I got it figured out thank you!